# how to copy text content from ubuntu to windows environment

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-11.04

Present i am using windows7 in my machine recently installed Ubuntu through oracle virtual box manager as per my requirement some times i need to copy files and copy text content to windows environment and copy text from windows to ubuntu.

let me know if have any easy solutions to access.

Answer (score 1):

For copying text using the clipboard, do [Devices->Install Guest Additions.](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp7254976).

For sharing files use [shared folders](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders).

Answer (score 0):

For copying text content between the host and the VB Ubuntu 16.04 guest, follow these steps:
1- go to VB manager window and right click on you device (your guest Device) and select "Setting".
2- Go to "Advanced" tab and select "Bidirectional" for both "Shared Clipboard" and "Drag'N'Drop".Press Ok.

This should make it to work, but if it does not, then, do the followings in addition:

1- On VB manager window right click on your device and select "Settings"
2- Click "Storage" on the left panel and to click the disk icon under the "controller IDE".
3- On the right panel, under the "Attributes> Optical Drive", click the disk icon.
4- Select "Choose Virtual Optical Disk File" and browse to  "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox" and select "VBoxGuestAdditions.iso" and press"Open".
5- Restart your VB.